# TableView not populating with array data

Tags: swift, uitableview

I need to populate my third tableview based on which cell the user tapped on the last tableview. I successfully did this from the first tableview to the second tableview but cannot do it to the third.  I am using tableview controllers

**I need to find out how I can make the numberOfSections equal to categories.items.count**

Heres my class...

```
struct Item {
let name: String
let carbs: Int
}
struct Category {
   let name: String
   let items: [Item]
}

struct Restaurant {
    let name: String
    let categories: [Category]

}
```

Heres where I append...

```
  let shake = Item(name: "Shake", carbs: 20)
    let fries = Item(name: "Fries", carbs: 30)
    let pie = Item(name: "Pie", carbs: 23)

    let beverages = Category(name: "Beverages", items: [shake])
    let chips_fries = Category(name: "Chips & Fries", items: [fries])
    let desserts = Category(name: "Desserts", items: [pie])
    let other = Category(name: "Other Menu Items", items: [])
    let sandwiches_burgers = Category(name: "Sandwiches & Burgers", items: [])
    let sides = Category(name: "Sides", items: [])

    a_w = Restaurant(name: "A&W", categories: [beverages, chips_fries, desserts, other, sandwiches_burgers, sides])

    restaurants = [a_w]
```

Heres where I attempt to populate

```
    var categories = [Category]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tableView.reloadData()
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let category = categories[indexPath.section]
    let item = category.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = item.name
    return cell
}
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categories.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let category = categories[section]
    return category.items.count
}
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate and datasource for tableview correctly?

Comment: I am using tableview controllers @Luzo

Comment: Where do you register the type of cell to create for the cell identifier "cell"?

Comment: You don't have to set the delegate/datasource when you are using a `UITableViewController` (notice the `override` keyword in front of tableView functions). I suggest you to breakpoint your tableview methods and double check if they are getting called.

Comment: Its on the storyboard. @ScottThompson

Comment: I reload tableview in viewdidLoad. @dvdblk

Comment: And where do you set your categories? I see only empty array initialization. Did you set it?

Comment: categories is an Array of Category which is appended to in the section labeled append. `let beverages = Category(...` @Luzo

Comment: @johnd337 and counts for sections and number of rows in section are correct?

Comment: Breakpoint your `cellForRowAt` function and check your variables in the debugger. Feel free to share the result..

Comment: How would I make the numberOfRows in Section equal to categories.items.count? @Luzo

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If your data is filled correctly then your code should work. As @dvdblk said, we need to see your values, we cannot help you further without the debug info.